# Reversing string segments within query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a text column that contains values like `CN-CHGO-BNSF`.

I need to reverse the order of the segments between hyphens. So the example above would be converted to `BNSF-CHGO-CN`. I can easily do this in C# code, but here I could optimize my task if I could do it within a query.

Is there any way to do this in a SQL query? I'm using Entity Framework and SQL Server. Is this possible?

The number of segments will be one or more. (The number of hyphens will be zero or more.)

##### Examples

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| BNSF | BNSF |
| CHGO-BNSF | BNSF-CHGO |
| CN-CHGO-BNSF | BNSF-CHGO-CN |
| FXE-EAGPA-BNSF-ROBSP-(RVPR) | (RVPR)-ROBSP-BNSF-EAGPA-FXE |

With SQL Server 2022, it looks like [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is being added (which I'm not currently using). I don't know if that could be used for this.

Comment: Please show the output you want for your example

Comment: Always 2 hyphens? From n to m hyphens? Any number of hyphens?

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT: I included the output, it's `BNSF-CHGO-CN`.

Comment: @allmhuran: One or more segments, zero or more hyphens.

Comment: For a fixed number of hyphens there are semi-reasonable answers, for N hyphens where N >= 0 it is possible, but impractical, to do it in T-SQL (eg, turn the string into a table of segments, read the table in order of position descending, reconstruct the string)

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) (KB5014353) - 15.0.4236.7 (X64). But I'd consider an upgrade if it could solve this issue.

Comment: You can always write your own table value udf that splits strings, then reverse and concatenate using stuff and for xml.

Comment: String_split in SQL 2022 has an optional ordinal position which likely would let you split the string and then string_agg using the order by descending.  You may need to remove an extra - at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a maximum number of positions, you can use a bit of JSON in concert with `concat()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('BNSF')
,('CHGO-BNSF')
,('CN-CHGO-BNSF')
,('FXE-EAGPA-BNSF-ROBSP-(RVPR)')

Select A.*
      ,NewVal = stuff( concat('-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]')
                             ,'-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]')
                             ,'-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
                             ,'-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
                             ,'-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
                             ,'-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
                             ,'-'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
                      ),1,1,'')
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),'-','","')+'"]' ) ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]

**EDIT Using String_AGG**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.NewValue
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select NewValue = string_agg(value,'-') within group (ORDER BY convert(int,[key]) desc)
                  from openjson( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),'-','","')+'"]' ) 
             ) B
```

Comment: Thanks. Kind of ugly but it does the task. I'm not sure what the limit is, but it's not very high.

Comment: @JonathanWood You could always do a string_agg() within the cross apply, but I honestly suspect that would be less performant

Comment: @JonathanWood See EDIT Using String_AGG

Comment: `[key] as int desc` otherwise '10' < '2'

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to optimize my code by doing it all within a query. I like the simplicity of your second example. But I'm not sure about the performance of this. I may just pull the needed rows down and parse them in my code.

Comment: @JonathanWood the first option had a relative batch of 6% while the string_agg approach had a whopping 94%.   My suspicion was correct... It may be ugly but it is more performant

Comment: @lptr You are 100% correct.  Good catch.

Comment: @JonathanWood If your data is as clean as your sample, you can tweak it a bit by removing the string_escape( ) function

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is generic and will work for any number of tokens in a column.

It is using XML and XQuery to tokenize tokens in a column.
After that XQuery's FLWOR expression is traversing tokens in a reverse order via `order by $pos descending`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT Into @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('BNSF'),
('CHGO-BNSF'),
('CN-CHGO-BNSF'),
('FXE-EAGPA-BNSF-ROBSP-(RVPR)');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-';

SELECT t.*
   , REPLACE(c.query('
      for $x in /root/r/text()
      let $pos := count(/root/r[. << $x[1]])
      order by $pos descending
      return data($x)
   ').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),SPACE(1), @separator) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BNSF | BNSF |
| 2 | CHGO-BNSF | BNSF-CHGO |
| 3 | CN-CHGO-BNSF | BNSF-CHGO-CN |
| 4 | FXE-EAGPA-BNSF-ROBSP-(RVPR) | (RVPR)-ROBSP-BNSF-EAGPA-FXE |